# How to use xlRange in Matlab when it is in a loop and avoid overwriting on same cell?

Tags: matlab

I have a loop where it keeps producing answers each time. I need to record about 200 of these answers in excel. But instead of writing one by one I thought of using xlswrite. 
Then I realised this keeps over writing the data on same cell.
Then I thought of xlRange but I don't know how to increase this from A1 to A2 so each loop answer gets recorded in a different cell.

```
xlswrite(filename,array,sheet,xlRange)
xlRange = 'A1'
```

This is what I am using currently but I need the xlRange to increase each time.

I am new to Matlab so is this a right command to use to be able to record my answers on excel. Also is there a way to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: I highly recommend against using `xlswrite` calls in a loop. It's incredibly slow (MATLAB opens/closes the ActiveX connection with every call). Store your data in a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) and write it when your lloop is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Following @excaza's advice, here's an example

```
toWrite = cell(5);
for k = 1:5
    toWrite{k, k} = char(97 + k - 1); % writes 'A', 'B', ..., 'E'
end
xlswrite('test.xlsx', toWrite);
```